# React hooks state is not updated right after it's set with async

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks

Is it not possible to get the updated hook value right after setting it? I assume react only updates value for the next render, since my screen following async-await renders fine. Just logs are not printing out the state I was expecting.

Not sure if I'm suppose to log state like this, or write another useEffect just for the states I need and put console.log in there instead?

```
const [uid, setUID] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
const [state, setState] = useState<{ [key: string]: any; } | undefined>();

const load = async () => {
  const currentUID = auth().currentUser?.uid;
  setUID(currentUID);

  console.log(uid); // returns undefined
  console.log(currentUID); // this prints fine

  await firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUID).get().then(docSnapshot => {
    setState(docSnapshot.data());
    console.log('Profile: loaded', state); // returns undefined
  });

  console.log(uid); // returns undefined even after await
  console.log('Profile: loaded', state); // returns undefined even after await
}

useEffect(() => { 
  load();
}, []);
```

Comment: You can't log state like that. React will discard state changes so only the "most recent" will render. I ran into this when I tried to use state for multiple modals, but only the latest modal showed up, previous ones were "lost".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updates are internally async, meaning state setter calls ( `setState()` from `useState` or `this.setState()` for class components) do not return a promise. This means that calling await on it isn't going to do anything, and synchronous logic after the await call is going to still run before state has been updated.

So there is a fix

```
// Either log it directly in the body of the function
console.log(state);

// ...Or in a useEffect call
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state);
}, [state]);

const handleEvent = e => {
  setState(e.target.value);
}
```

Or class components provide a callback.

`this.setState({value: newValue}, () => console.log(this.state.value))`

[Read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)